# Se me resetea la cookie cuando guardo 7 elementos en un array

Tags: php

tengo un array de objetos que lo guardo en una cookie con PHP mediante el siguiente código:

setcookie('carrito', serialize($carrito), time()+3600);

el problema es que cuando el array $carrito llega a los 7 elementos se resetea y me añade un array con un solo elemento en la cookie.